# Laptop locks after 2 minutes inactivity

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-management

I have windows 10 pro installed on my Acer Aspire F15 laptop. In all the power settings I said that the screen may **never** turn of (while using the battery, or with power plugged-in). and it may **never** go into sleep mode.

*But* after 2 minutes of inactivity, my screen locks and turns black.

I tried to look for an option in regedit, secpol, screensaver, power settings. But everywhere I look, there either isn't an option, or my computer doesn't recognize it by the looks of it.

I have some screens to prove the settings:

[image: Advanced power settings]

[image: Windows 10 power settings]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my screen keep locking every two minutes or so?](https://superuser.com/questions/1017626/why-does-my-screen-keep-locking-every-two-minutes-or-so)

Answer (score 0):

After searching around for a while I stumbled across this by CaesarMagnus.

> "I think I finally found the problem.
> There's a setting called "System unattended sleep timeout"
> However, in Windows 10 it does not show up in the Advanced Power Settings.
>
> I had to add it through a registry edit from here (the Windows 7 regedit works on Windows 10)
> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/246364-power-options-add-system-unattended-sleep-timeout.html
>
> So far it has not gone to sleep after two minutes when I wake it with my mouse.
>
> So, it looks like a Microsoft problem, not hardware."

After changing the registry using the link he provided, I was able to change that setting, and it fixed my issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Just FYI, we try to link questions that are the same.  It makes the collection of answers easier to find.  When you come across several questions that one answer solves, it's an indication that the questions may be duplicates.  Rather than post the same answer on multiple questions if they are asking the same thing, it's better to pick one to answer, and then flag the other question as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is almost [the same as user870042's](https://superuser.com/a/1292632/167207), except:

1. the registry key did exist on my Windows 10 pc. It can be found by searching for "Console lock display off timeout" in the registry. Then in Regedit change the Attribute of the key you found to "2".
2. Now in control panel, Power Options, Advanced Power Options, open Display and there should be an option "Console lock display off timeout". If it is low (like 1 minute) increase it.

   Thanks to answer by JennyFung at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/88362/how-do-i-change-the-time-untill-my-pc-locks.html .