# Why does lid close powercfg setting not work after switching users?

Tags: laptop, windows-11, sleep, power-management

I think I had changed my powercfg settings so my laptop wouldn't sleep on lid close. Then I followed an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/874849/change-what-closing-the-lid-does-from-the-commandline/1380744#1380744) and changed them so lid close would sleep.

When I restarted my computer and logged in, sleep worked on lid close.

However, when I change users, the effect doesn't last, even if I switch back to my profile, add the settings for the other user, etc.

Here is the relevant setting in powercfg though it isn't working as I switched users:

```
  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
      GUID Alias: LIDACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
```

Also my lid close settings in Windows all say Do Nothing and I can't save the changes I make to them.

[image]

**Update:**

I followed some info [here](https://superuser.com/a/1324784/104438) and edited a registry value which was 0. Now it is 1:

[image]

However, I still see "Do Nothing" even after saving changes of it to "Sleep", and more surprisingly I no longer see this `(Lid close action)` Power Setting GUID in my `powercfg /q`. Lid close still partially works as before (sleeps in my profile, but not if I switch user or switch back).

**Update 2**:

Also noting after reading [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/872378/my-laptop-will-not-sleep-when-i-close-the-lid?rq=1), that I don't have the Lid Close settings available here:

[image]

I edited the registry back to 0, and now see the lid close GUID in `powercfg /d`. However I still don't see it in the above menu (and haven't since first observing this problem).

**Update 3:**

I created a new plan and was able to change the settings, but sleep (or hibernate) on lid close still doesn't work after changing users.

[image]