# Windows 11 Lenovo Laptop not sleeping when I close the lid

Tags: laptop, windows-11, battery, sleep, power-management

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 that I bought new two months ago, and it is running Windows 11. I have no idea why, but starting a few days ago, whenever I close the lid of my laptop, it doesn't sleep. This winds up draining my battery to death when the lid is closed.

I don't know why this is happening but it did seem to only start to occur after I installed an update to Windows 11 - I update Windows 11 every few weeks because my computer tells me I should.

Does anyone know how to get my laptop to **actually** sleep when I close the lid so that it doesn't drain the battery?

[image]

Comment: So your screenshot doesn’t actually show us the settings we need to make that particular screenshot helpful. I mean your laptop is currently configured to never go into hybrid sleep just from that screenshot

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what "hybrid sleep" is and I don't think I've ever even heard that term. Also, the screenshot isn't necessarily supposed to give all relevant information. I included the "power options" window because in this answer (https://superuser.com/questions/872378/my-laptop-will-not-sleep-when-i-close-the-lid), there is a tab that says "power options and lid", but my laptop doesn't have this.

Comment: Try resetting your power plan to defaults and see if suspend returns.

Comment: Also I'd appreciate if you didn't roast me immediately for asking an innocent question. "Oh hey your screenshot is useless btw." Like dude just help me; don't roast me straight out of the gate. I don't understand why this community has to be so toxic.

Comment: Thank you John. Thank worked! :D

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Comment: @Ben -Hybrid Sleep is the default state Windows uses when you put your system to sleep, unless you disable it, which I don’t disabling. I didn’t say your screenshot was useless, I said it wasn’t helpful, to diagnose what was actually happening. If you were offended by that statement then I apologize

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you @John. Thank worked! :D

Given your post, I suggest resetting your current Power Plan to default settings, restart and test.

I think that should work