# Dell 3140 - Closing Lid does not put laptop Win 11 in Sleep Mode despite correct setting

Tags: laptop, windows-11, sleep, power-management, dell-latitude

I have Dell Latitude 3140 Notebook. It was recently purchased from Amazon US and hand carried to my country. So no warranty is possible now.

It has Windows 11 Pro OS on it. The BIOS, Graphics drivers & OS are the latest.
In power options, I have set the Lid Closed action as Sleep for both On battery as well as Plugged In.

Despite when closing the Lid, the Laptop remains ON. I tried changing it to Shutdown, Hibernate etc but still it remains ON.

Sleep, when invoked by Sleep option or pressing power button works fine.

I have read following links but nothing worked. I also tried restoring system to an earlier date but that did not help. I believe this issue is there right from day 1, just that we realized it now. Fast startup is OFF. I also tried the troubleshooter but that did not help. Resetting power options did not help.

[https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000149580/why-is-my-system-not-going-to-sleep-mode#:~:text=You%20can%20run%20the%20Windows,display%20or%20entering%20sleep%20mode](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000149580/why-is-my-system-not-going-to-sleep-mode#:%7E:text=You%20can%20run%20the%20Windows,display%20or%20entering%20sleep%20mode).

https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/windows-general/computer-not-sleeping-when-lid-closed/647f950af4ccf8a8de7786df

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-laptop-no-longer-sleeping-when-lid/09109584-9b83-4832-8a18-85f11b280082

[Windows 11 Lenovo Laptop not sleeping when I close the lid](https://superuser.com/questions/1817114/windows-11-lenovo-laptop-not-sleeping-when-i-close-the-lid)

Any further advice how to fix this would be great.
One thing to note s that it’s a Dual mode laptop, i.e. when completely turned the screen 180 Deg the Laptop turns into a Tablet.

Edit 1 - The issue appears even with Clean Boot Windows 11. So there's no conflicting service in question!

Comment: If all the drivers are up to date and the issue was there when you purchased the machine, you might consider backing up and installing Windows fresh.  Settings, Update, Advanced, Recovery and system reset

Comment: Obviously the whole purpose of doing this much troubleshooting is to avoid Clean Install or Refresh Windows.

Comment: I suggested my approach because Lid Close has worked properly for me for many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further troubleshooting I have finally solved this issue. Since most of the Software & OS troubleshooting did not help, I decided to look into the Firmware (BIOS/UEFI whatever you call it).

In Dell 3140 Laptop’s BIOS, under Power options there’s a toggle button for Lid Switch. It was Off, as a result OS was ignoring the Lid Closed Event. I turned it to ON and now Windows 11 faithfully follows the Lid Closed event and puts the laptop into Sleep mode.

I have handled several laptops from HP, Lenovo, Acer etc but I am noticing this functionality for the first time in Dell’s BIOS.

This is self-answered, just in case anyone else has similar issue and are looking for solutions. This could be one of the pointers to check. The title is slightly modified for better search Indexing.

[image]